# Filtros avanzados con CURL

Tags: curl, swagger

Buenos dias. Estoy realizando busquedas a una base de datos a traves de una API llamada Swagger, la cual usa Curl para las busquedas. Queria saber si usando curl es posible hacer uso de filtros combinados, es decir, si yo busco las personas que sean hombre y mayores de 25, que me saque los sujetos que cumplan ambas condiciones (la orden curl que ejecuta me saca todos los hombres, y todos los mayores de 25).
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola Antonio. Has de presentar el codigo intentado hasta ahora explicando qué problemas te encuentras o erroes generados. Recuerda visitar [ask] para aprender a hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: Más que una cuestión de cURL sería una cuestión de si el API de Swagger lo soporta; a cURL le pasas parámetros y el te monta la llamada HTTP que necesites... Lo dicho, mira la documentación de Swagger